# AWS alexa support subdomains?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

We have implemented the Alexa skill with Node.js application. But the Node.js application domain is sub-domain like https://test.example.com/,

Does Alexa support sub-domains?

Comment: How the domain related to Alexa? Are you using it as an API endpoint? Then that should not make any difference

Comment: No its not an API end point, Its just Nodejs application only.

Comment: Are you using it instead of lambda function? Did I get it right?

Comment: No we did not using lambda function. Actually i we added alexa functionality through routes in nodejs application.





Clear Example: If we need to restart the nodejs application, At that alexa will restart the application. Also in application got any error alexa will send the errors.





The above functionality we try to implement, our domain is subdomain that's why we confused alexa will support for subdomain or not.






If you have understand my query please reply and thanks for your time & response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it shouldn't matter if you have a subdomain for your end point as long as it matches the requirements alexa specifies
for more information on that check the [alexa documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/host-a-custom-skill-as-a-web-service.html)